# DLookup produces runtime error 2471 - No error trapping that I have tried works

Tags: vba, dlookup

The exact wording of the error displayed is "Run-time error: The expression you entered as a query perameter produced this error:" and it then gives "`ThisCode`"

```
Function GetCageFileNumber(ThisCode As String) As Integer
    
    Dim sSQL As String
    
    If IsError(DLookup("[Sequence]", "CageSequence", "[CageCode] = " & ThisCode)) Then GoTo NewCage
    
    GetCageFileNumber = DLookup("[Sequence]", "CageSequence", "[CageCode] = " & ThisCode) + 1
    
    sSQL = "UPDATE CageSequence SET [Sequence] = " & GetCageFileNumber & " WHERE [CageCode] = " & ThisCode
    
    dbs.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

    Exit Function

NewCage:
    
    GetCageFileNumber = 1
    
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO CageSequence (" & ThisCode & " , 1)"

    dbs.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

End Function
```

This really is a question of - How do you trap a `DLookup` runtime error?
I've tried a few variations but so far nothing traps the error!
I have set this up to produce an error. "`ThisCode`" is not contained in the table "`CageSequence`". I need to trap this runtime error (2471) so as to be able to drop into "`NewCage:`" to be able to add the "`ThisCode`" to the "`CageSequence`" table.

Comment: Domain aggregate functions return Null when there is no match found - except for DCount which returns 0. Function is declared as Integer type and cannot hold Null. Only Variant can hold Null. Use Nz() function to deal with possible Null return. Also, text fields need apostrophe delimiters for parameters. ThisCode is declared as a String type variable, it is not a value: `"[CageCode] = '" & ThisCode & "'"`.

Comment: I don't think IsError works the way you expect (I've never used it). Use error handling code to trap runtime errors. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find a reason for this lack of error trapping. I have my suspicion that if the value Dlookup is looking for does not exist in the table then an untrapable error occurs. It's just a suspicion and I have no way of confirming if this is the case. In the end I coded around the problem as below:-

```
Function FindCageFileNumber(ThisCode As String) As Integer

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM CageSequence")
    
FindCageFileNumber = -1

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF = True
    
    If rs!CageCode = ThisCode Then
        FindCageFileNumber = rs!Sequence + 1
        rs.Edit
        rs!Sequence = FindCageFileNumber
        rs.Update
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

If FindCageFileNumber = -1 Then
    rs.AddNew
    rs!CageCode = ThisCode
    rs!Sequence = 1
    rs.Update
    FindCageFileNumber = 1
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```